# Getting the selected row from dataGridView1

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a dataGridView1 on my Wondows Form Application. I have populated the dataGridView1 with a list of strings. This all works great. But...

I need to be able to grab the row the user is selected on and I can't seem to do it. My code just gives me an error, written below.

I have copied GridViewRow form the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow(v=vs.110).aspx) site.

```
private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        GridViewRow row =  dataGridView1.SelectedRow;

        //This is what I have been using before with a list box.
        if (itemList.SelectedIndex >= 0) {
            int newInt = itemList.SelectedIndex;
            Form form = new NewItemW(selectedFolder, this, items[newInt], WindowEnum.ItemEdit);
            form.Show();
        }
    }
```

I have tried this but I am getting the error: "The type or namespace 'GridViewRow' could not be found."

My basic question is how do I get this to work?

Comment: I know the error is for a using statement that I am missing but I don't know which one.

Comment: `DataGridViewRow`. Don't forget to check like this: `if (dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)..`  `GridViewRow` is for `GridsViews` in `WPF`

Comment: Also: There is no `SelectedRow` in a `Winforms DataGridView`, instead you can access `dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0]`

Comment: Ohh I see. Yes I'll be adding the check after I get it working thanks. Did you want to turn this into an answer so I can make this the correct answer?

Comment: @TaW Thanks for adding that I was going to ask you about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `Winforms DataGridView` you should do it like this:

```
private void editButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   if (DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
   {
      DataGridViewRow row =  dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0];
      if (itemList.SelectedIndex >= 0) 
      {
         int newInt = itemList.SelectedIndex;
         Form form = new NewItemW(
                         selectedFolder, this, items[newInt], WindowEnum.ItemEdit);
         form.Show();
      }
   }
}
```

By copying from that link you have mixed the WPF Controls and their code with Winforms. Often folks mix up just the names `DataGridView` vs `GridViewRow`, but you have also copied the wong Property `SelectedRow`. Instead use the first element of the `SelectedRows` collection. Also always check or else the array acess will crash..

Comment: One more question. I'm trying to get rid of my itemList which is used in a listBox. How would I get the [0] to be replaced by the row that I actually have selected?

Comment: Well, you will have to tell me what the __relation__ of the `ListBox` and the `DGV` is. As it is, `row` is not even used yet..

Comment: _How would I get the [0] to be replaced by the row that I actually have selected?_ [0] is the index of the first row. and not the frist row in the dgv but the first row in the __SelectedRows__! (meansing selected in the DGV; selection in the listbox is another matter, which you would have to explain either to me/us or your machine..

Comment: I was just wondering how I could get rid of the listBox in general. I know I can just stop using it but I wanted the same functionality. My original program was a little hacky. I didn't know about DataGridViews before so I was using a listBox. I figured it out though. 'dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Index' is what I needed. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

you are using the web control System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.GridViewRow, it must be hosted in a web page.
For windows form use the System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewRow control.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow(v=vs.110)